# Fields of an Object retrieved using Ant has <encrypted> property

Tags: apex, deployment, ant, migration-tool, encryption

I retrieved an object using ant tool using `retrieveUnpackaged` command.I retrieved this from a higher environment of my project.. say the SIT environment(Full Sandbox). On looking at the fields( text fields only) I found that it has a property `<encrypted>` added to it like below. **This is a normal text field and not encrypted type.**

```
<fields>
    <fullName>atext__c</fullName>
    <deprecated>false</deprecated>
    **<encrypted>false</encrypted>**
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <formula>xxx</formula>
    <label>xxx</label>
    <required>false</required>
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
    <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
    <type>Text</type>
    <unique>false</unique>
</fields>
```

On checking the field on Custom object from the UI , I do not see any property for `encryption` available. I thought , ok! this must be added by salesforce by default for all text fields. hmmm.. But I retrieved the same object from by Development org(DEV) and I noticed that there is no such property there:

```
<fields>
    <fullName>atext__c</fullName>
    <deprecated>false</deprecated>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <formula>xxx</formula>
    <label>xxx</label>
    <required>false</required>
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
    <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
    <type>Text</type>
    <unique>false</unique>
</fields>
```

I have been now wondering why the object from SIT org has `<encrypted>` added to it but it not in DEV org. Anyone had this discrepancy? or any reason Salesforce would add this property to a Full Sandbox org but not to a developer pro/developer org?

**Update:**
I see that platform encryption is created under setup->platform Encryption in Full Sandbox but it is not there in Dev Sandbox. This be the reason?